# useRef Hook issue - ref.current.link.click() firing continuously

Tags: reactjs, use-ref

```
         const csvLinkRef = useRef(null)

        const exportFile = () => {
          let data= {data:'info'}

          //Async Action
          dispatch(
            getFileData(data, 
                ()=>{
                   csvLinkRef.current.link.click()
                }
          ))
        }

          <Button onClick={exportFile}> //run exportFile on click

           <CSVLink 
              filename={'file.csv'}
              data={someData}
              ref={csvLinkRef}//set ref here
            >                          
             Export
            </CSVLink>

          </Button>


//Async API call using redux thunk
export const getFileData = (data,cb) => async dispatch => {
  try{
    const res = await callApi('ever.php',data,'POST')// make api call 
    if(res.status==="00"){
      dispatch({
        type:GET_ALL_DATA,
        data: res.data,
      })
    }
  }catch(error){
    console.log(error)
  }finally{
    cb()
  }
}
```

My issue is csvLinkRef.current.link.click() fires non-stop after the API call. How can I make it fire just once? Is there a way I can 'unset' the ref? Please help.(I'm using react-csv library).
The getFileData action API call is successful and the data is in redux state.
if csvLinkRef.current.link.click fired only once, everything would be fine

Comment: Can you provide more context? What about `getFileData` and how you call `exportFile`?

Comment: Button doesnt have a closing tag and CSVLink has two data. If you could provide more information of the data used to get us understand more on what is been dispatched and fetched

Comment: I edited the question. Is there something else I should add?

Comment: someData is an array of the data fetched

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Now it is solved. You can try it...

```html
function CsvExample({ manufacturerList }: IdLinkCreateProps) {
    const httpRequests = new HttpRequests()
    const csvInstance = useRef<any | null>(null);

    const [alertOpt, setAlertOpt] = useState({ isOpen: false, message: '', variant: '' })
    const [manufacturer, setManufacturer] = useState<IManufacturerItem | null>(null)
    const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState<number>(0)
    const [idList, setIdList] = useState<{ idList: string }[]>([])

    const header = [{ label: "Digital-Links", key: "idLink" }];

    const createIdLink = async () => {
        let data: IIdLinkCreate = { manufacturer: manufacturer!, quantity: quantity! }
        try {
            const result = await httpRequests.idLinkCreate(data)
            setSuccessOptions(result)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('error on getting trusted manufacturer list: ', error);
        }
        return
    }

    const setSuccessOptions = (result: IBackendResult) => {
        if (result.success) {
            setIdList(result.data);

        } else {
            setAlertOpt({ isOpen: true, message: 'FAILED', variant: 'danger' })
            console.log('error on updating data: ', result.error);
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if (idList && idList.length > 0 && csvInstance?.current?.link) {
            csvInstance.current.link.click();
        }
    }, [idList]);

    return (
        <div className='id_link_wrapper'>
            <AppHeader />

            <Alert className="alert_error" variant={alertOpt.variant} show={alertOpt.isOpen} >
                {alertOpt.message}
            </Alert>

            <IdLinkTitlePart />
            <IdLinkInputPart
                manufacturerList={manufacturerList}
                setManufacturer={setManufacturer}
                setQuantity={setQuantity}
                quantity={quantity}
            />

            <Button
                onClick={createIdLink}
                className='button_element'> CSV EXPORTIEREN
            </Button>
            <CSVLink
                asyncOnClick={true}
                headers={header}
                data={idList!}
                filename="bsedata.csv"
                data-interception='off'
                ref={csvInstance}
            />
        </div>
    )
}

export default CsvExample
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).